# Get Package Name of Main Apk from Wearable apk

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a Wearable application that needs to know the main applications packageName.  Is there a way to get the package name of the main apk from the wearable apk (on the watch)?

Comment: You need to have the same `packageName` (now `applicationId` I beleive) on the wearable apk if the wearable apk is embedded into the main apk. Is it not the case??

Comment: I have an app offered both free and paid each with a different package names.  This is a library that I use within the wearables app.  So, I need to get the packageName of the library project from the wearables.

Comment: Can you not include the packageName in the BuildConfig (via gradle) when building the app?

Comment: The structure of my code is different.  I have launcher activities that actually launch (build) the application that allows me to easily change the packageName for clients.  My library and wearables do share the same package name, but not the package name I need.  I am trying now to pass a value from the phone (it's a boolean value) to the watch and can't figure out how to retrieve this.  Any ideas here...if I get this, I can provide the correct package name needed for what I am trying to accomplish.